# How can I get back the data of hard disk on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04

I was trying to install the Windows version next to Ubuntu on the hard disk with the knowledge that Ubuntu is very hard on SSD Jet Jet Windows version on the hard disk Format work for all the data to it and I do not know how to return the data can be as long as I can help me return it Tani and no solution and everything Permanently delete ??

Comment: Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/286181/367990 - this is about the other way round (trying to recover Windows data after installing Ubuntu) but the procedure should be nearly the same. *Don't do anything on the Windows system you installed on the disk though!* Every single disk write reduces the chances to recover files.

Comment: Although I tried to install Windows but it did not happen only the version data is the one on the hard disk and my data is deleted

Comment: "Ubuntu is very hard on SSD?" Can you please cite a reliable source for that?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17-Lo74Rqa-nNvd5uv3GVHbCUDVWn8AWB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This picture shows what I say